# In Germany, can I register for an Anmeldung before I have found permanent accomodation?

Tags: germany, residency, accommodation

The Anmeldung (citizen registration) is required for opening a bank account. I am currently staying at an AirBnb. I have read that landlord confirmation is required to receive an Anmeldung.

I have heard that it might be possible to register my company's office as my address. Is this possible? Will the registration office ask questions about the nature of the address?

Comment: Sorry, but it's "Anmeldung". "Abmeldung" is the exact opposite; that's what you do when you leave and tell them that you're leaving.

Comment: Hello vaughan, I have the same problem right now, how did you got through it?

Comment: @Rhei I found a place, then did the Anmeldung. I've heard you can put an office address. Or go stay in a hotel for a night - I think they are legally obliged to do it.

Comment: Therefore you do not need a rental agreement to do the Anmeldung? As I was thinking to rent a small apartment in a ferienwohnpark and then start looking for a permanent accommodation.

Comment: @Rhei I didn't show my rental agreement. Just the Wohnungsgeberbestätigung.

Comment: One more question, how did you do for the bank account? What address did you used?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you would confirm false data to the government, which is a criminal offence, so don't do that, even if the probability of being punished is low. Second, your company could get problems and they won't be happy about it.

AFAIK it's not required to show a contract to Einwohnermeldeamt, but it might be required to show some proof you actually live there (you should have some confirmation from AirBnb you've booked your current appartment).

If you have any doubts, you should ask in Einwohnermeldeamt, and going there, simply take booking and payment confirmation, just in case.

Comment: From what I have read you need a letter from the landlord to confirm your address as of 2015. This would certainly not be possible with AirBnb.

Comment: You should confirm this in the Amt, and ask if the lanlord is legally obliged to give you that letter (which would be logical, since you are obliged to register).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to register a bogus address, and it is not legal to do so.

You can register without permanent accommodation (for example in a short term, fully furnished apartment). However, you can only register your address with the permission of the landlord. The landlord or the main tenant will give you a [Wohnungsgeberbestätigung](https://allaboutberlin.com/glossary/Wohnungsgeberbest%C3%A4tigung) which you MUST show during the Anmeldung. Without that document, you can't complete the Anmeldung. You won't get that document with hotels and vacation rentals.

As far as I know, there is no way around this. You must find a real place to live, and get the permission from the landlord to live there.

[This Anmeldung guide](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/anmeldung-in-english-berlin) explains the requirements for an address registration, and cites legal sources where applicable.